# Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. > Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android

I know there are very similar questions asked previously but before I make any drastic changes I thought I would post the question here first.

This is the error I'm getting. 
My build.gradle is like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.microsoft.graph.helpdesk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }
    configurations {
        all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Azure AD
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.baoyachi:StepView:1.9'
    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.6'
    compile(project(':o365-auth'))

    // Dagger compiler for DI annotation support
    annotationProcessor 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.5'
    provided('com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.5')

    // Butterknife
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.graph:msgraph-sdk-android:1.1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0-rc2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

    // Test libraries
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'

}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried all the other solutions I could find but nothing has worked so far.
If anyone has any help at all it would be much appreciated

[EDIT] I have actually tried to run three other projects using API 27 and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at project ':o365-auth' that helped me to compile it;
try adal latest version or design instead appcompat etc

```
dependencies {
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

    // Dependency injection
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.5'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.5'

    // Azure AD
    compile 'com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.12.0'
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it fixed my problem, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

compile(project(':o365-auth'))
have similar issues;
prev on 23 and 23.0.3 all work good

tried upper gradle but same issues on 25 too